# ASP.NET Core Web API Docker Linux refused to connect

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, wsl-2

I've created a new project in VS 2019 with the following options:
Template: "ASP.NET Core Web Application" for C#

On the Advanced options, I've enabled everything: "Configure for HTTPS", "Enable Docker Support" in Linux, "Enable OpenAPI support".

However even with a default template configuration, when I start it, it refuses to connect to the browser.
This is a 100% default project from the Template.

I've also tried creating a project without SLL to see if that was the problem but no.

I've been around this for the last hour and I can't figure out what is going on.

I'm running a Windows 10 10 Pro 20H2, with Docker Desktop 3.0.0 (50684) with WSL2 enabled and Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.8.1.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I've just tested doing everything the same, but this time using Docker on Windows and it works. 
So it's something when docker is running in Linux context clearly.

Comment: Check that it is listening on `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1` when running in docker.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: `docker ps` show the port that are open through docker, and `docker logs (container id)` should show the listening ports.

Comment: Ok thanks. 
Yes it's listening to 0.0.0.0
"tail -f /dev/null"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:49170->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49169->443/tcp

Comment: so if you do a `telnet (host ip) 49170` from the host - do it connect?

Comment: I'm confused with the request of "from the host", I'm the host as this is a development environment currently. 
I've ran it as "telnet localhost 49170" and "telnet localhost 49169" and I get back: 
"Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 49170: Connect failed"

Comment: @Ralms, where did you access the docker, on linux or windows. Are they the same IP? Because you use `localhost`.  Whether the external port of docker is accessible, whether asp.net core is enabled to allow all IP access？

Comment: @Karney it's Docker for Desktop running on my Windows workstation, with WSL 2 enabled. I've tried to understand that, how is the port mapping, etc being made but I hasn't been clear yet. 
At the same time, if it was an issue with docker directly I would expect the Windows containers version of it to have the same issue and they work fine with localhost.